# NetBeans IDE 11.2 java application (jframe) export

Tags: java, swing, jframe, applet

I created a java application (jframe) in NetBeans IDE but I am struggling with integrating it on my website. 
I am a complete novice in java but instructions I found on official NetBeans website and on forums are not really helpful. 
I tried the applet method but it did not work (maybe because I am doing it wrong?).
Would be grateful if someone could clarify the process for me.

Comment: Applets are dead technology, modern browsers no longer support it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh, as I said, I am really new to Java.. What can I use instead?

Comment: *"What can I use instead?"* There is no replacement or alternative for Java based apps.

Comment: You could use something like Vaadin, but this requires that you also have a Java backend server.